# Stop or Start setitimer

Tags: c, linux, benchmarking

I have set up a timer successfully but I have one small issue, whenever my alarm expires and the catch_alarm function is called, I would like the that **the timer stops and only restarts when in returns to the main function** . Basically I need to perform some benchmarks (packets received and send from different interfaces) but I would not like to include the time it takes to do that processing as it would not reflect the true Rx and Tx rates accurately

The code sample is shown:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void catch_alarm (int sig)
{
    //Stop timer here
    printf("CALLING INTERRUPT NOW\n");
    sleep(1);
    signal (sig, catch_alarm);
    //Start it here again
}

/*void waste (void)
{
printf("hello 1\n");
while(1)
{
printf("hello 2\n");
}
printf("hello 3\n");
}*/



struct itimerval old;
struct itimerval new;

int main(void)
{
    signal (SIGALRM, catch_alarm);
    new.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    new.it_interval.tv_usec = 500000;
    new.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    new.it_value.tv_usec = 500000;

    old.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    old.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    old.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    old.it_value.tv_sec = 0;


    if (setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &new, &old) < 0)
        printf("Timer init failed\n");

    else
        printf("Timer init succeeded\n");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("in while loop\n");
        //sleep(10);
        //waste();
        printf("Resuming from sleep\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: Would sigaction be better suited here, if so, how ?

Comment: I am unable to understand what exactly you are trying to do here(specially from the code snippet) , could you elaborate more ...

Comment: I am simply bench-marking. Some variable is being incremented in some loop within the main function and I want to print its value every one (or any number of seconds). I don't want the time that the **catch_alarm** function takes to be an added as an un-necessary overhead to my Rx/Tx rates